# XML processing with hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

I have an XML file of the following nature.

```
<TREE>
 <SUBTREE> some_text1 </SUBTREE>
 <SUBTREE> some_text2 </SUBTREE>
</TREE>
```

I have 10 nodes in my cluster and I want each mapper to get a SUBTREE each time the 'map' method is called i.e when the map method is called the first time the map running on all the 10 nodes are able to access the first SUBTREE element, similarly when it is called the second time all the 10 nodes are able to access the second SUBTREE element in the XML file. Is there a way in which I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB feature available to do this. You have to write your custom InputFormat for this that'll implement the recordreader as per your requirement. You might find this link helpful :
http://www.undercloud.org/?p=408